# Drag a straight line from Sprite to finger location in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm wondering if the problem has something to do with the arrangement of my nodes rather than with the code, but I can't seem to get this line to work properly. I'd like to draw a straight, draggable line from the touched node to the position of the touch. The node will then move to the position where the touch is ended. My code is based on some of what I've seen here, but still can't get it to show up. This relevant node is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, and this code is located in that class rather than in the main `GameScene` class.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.childNode(withName: "line")?.removeFromParent()  // Remove any previous line
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return } 
    let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self.parent!)  // Use 'parent' here? 
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    let line = SKShapeNode(path: path)  // Create shape node with path as path
    line.name = "line"
    line.zPosition = 5000  // Just trying to make sure it's on top
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    line.lineWidth = 20
    line.fillColor = UIColor.red
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.position.x, y: self.position.y))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: positionInScene.x, y: positionInScene.y))
    self.addChild(line)
}
```

When I create and add the path in `touchesBegan` it shows up, but that draws a bunch of lines, where I only want one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake. Just have to assign `path` to the line after it's been drawn.

```
let path = CGMutablePath()    
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.position.x, y: self.position.y))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: positionInScene.x, y: positionInScene.y))

let line = SKShapeNode(path: path)  // Create shape node with path as path
self.addChild(line)
```